# Azure B2C flow validating business logic through an Oauth2 API protection

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are creating an Azure B2C custom Policy and we would like to know if there is any way to call an external API that is protected by an oauth2.

I saw that is only possible to call an API that has Basic or Certificate validated.

Basic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-basic
Certificate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-cert

Comment: Good question. A workaround could be to add e.g. an Azure Function that the policy calls, which then does OAuth authentication and calls the API.

Comment: Yes thanks for the comment. Yes, so far it's what we are doing. We were trying to pass the secret/key from B2C to Az Function, but the xml config files from B2C custom policy are to hard. So we will try to modify the api to user certification validation or maybe using an Azure API Management to handle this. What do you think @juunas  :D